# Have this subclass of split graphs been studied before?

Tags: graph-theory, reference-request, terminology

I am interested in the  properties of the following subclass of split graphs:

The class consists of all split graphs $G=(C\cup I)$ where $C$ is a clique and $I$ an independent set, and *every* pair of vertices in $I$ have at least one common neighbor in $C$.

Does this class of graphs have a special name? Has this class and its properties been studied? If so, what would be some good references for this?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Split graphs of diameter 2?

Comment: I guess that's all that can be said about these. I searched far and wide, these don't seem to have any specific name. Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

I don't know if this can help you, but it's easy to see that your class is a superclass of connected threshold graphs. I think that the inclusion is strict, since $S_3$([link](http://wwwteo.informatik.uni-rostock.de/isgci/smallgraphs.html#S3)) is in your class, but is not a threshold graph.